# How to connect a external service to a queue through Gateway / Api Gateway / Rest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, gateway

I would like to allow to external service consume my RabbitMQ queues, the question is that I don´t want to give direct access connect to RabbitMQ I would like to expose through a Gateway / API Manager / Rest Endpoint.

I´m not sure if this is possible, but I would like to know some way to leave events in a queue that can be consumed by external services exposed in a security way or centralized like Gateway.

Thank you everybody that response : )

Answer (score 0):

You might try to create a callback service.

What the system will do is it will accept (or even store) `POST` URLs. When your *own* queue consumer consumes a message, what it will do is just send the queue message (maybe with add-on data) as a callback to the URLs you have stored. Then the servers the URL belongs to will do whatever they need to the messages sent by your callback service.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @KaNa0011, callbacks can be a solutions but this put some more responsibility on the producer (what if the receiver is not available ?)

Another approach is to expose your events as an Atom feed, this is something that is explained here by Oliver Gierke in his talk *"Refactoring to a System of System"* : https://youtu.be/MEySjYD86PQ?t=5487